# Find the percent overlap between two different images?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have 2 different images, one image is a red channel and another image is a green channel. I finally have a merged imaged which shows both red and green channels. I have attached all 3 images. Essentially, I want to find the percent overlap (how much of the green image is being overlapped with the red image. By this, the pixel overlap between red and green).

I was wondering what type of python package I could use or any other helpful advice that I can do this.

Overlay:

[image: overlay]

Green:

[image: green]

Red:

[image: red]

Comment: Colocalization is a difficult problem with many proposed solutions, all of which have downsides to them. Here's some examples: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/examples/python/colocalization.ipynb -- I suggest you read the literature about these methods before you decide to use any one of them.

Comment: These images seem heavily overexposed. You should avoid overexposure if you want a quantitative result.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can find the overlap regions of an image:

```
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
green = cv2.imread('test_images/green_image.jpg')
red = cv2.imread('test_images/red_image.jpg')

plt.imshow(green)
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(red)
```

[image]

```
green_grey = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
red_grey = cv2.cvtColor(red, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
bitwiseand = cv2.bitwise_and(green_grey, red_grey)
plt.imshow(bitwiseand)
```

[image]

```
type(bitwiseand)
>>> numpy.ndarray
bitwiseand.shape
>>> (532, 611)

total = green_grey+red_grey
total_pixels = total[total>0].shape[0]

matches = bitwiseand[bitwiseand > 0].shape[0]
percentage = (100*matches/total_pixels)
percentage
>>> 12.341323771795391%
```

So logically:

1. Load images into cv2 numpy arrays
2. Convert to greyscale
3. Use cv2 bitwise_and to find the overlaps
4. Divide the number of values that are `> 0` in bitwiseand & `> 0` in the added images together
5. that's it!

hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate the help! Im currently using pycharm and it gave me a cannot find reference "imread)  in "init.py". I will install another IDE and see if that works. Ty!

Comment: @RoyalShrestha try using anaconda distribution

Comment: @ferrariic Great answer. Keep in mind not to mix OpenCV and Matplotlib. The color channel order is different for both

Answer (score 0):

If the red and green channels are binarized, it suffices to count the green pixels and for every green pixel tell if there is a red in the other channel. It is an easy matter of scanning the images.

If the channels are not binarized, do binarize them and proceed as above.